# UIImageView in UITableViewCell repeat

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, repeat

I have a bug.
I want to display a `UIImageView` on cells at special `indexPath.row`, but these `UIImageView` repeat while I scroll.
Exemple: I display my `UIImageView` on a cell `indexPath.row` == 0, if I scroll down, I see my `UIImageView` on the cell at `indexPath.row` == 8.

Here is my code:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
            cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

        }

        UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UIImageView *imgRead = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:6];

        [cell.contentView insertSubview:imgRead aboveSubview:lblTemp1];

        contentDictio = [dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        lblTemp1.text = [contentDictio objectForKey:@"title"];

        NSArray *paths_id = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *basePath_id = ([paths_id count] > 0) ? [paths_id objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
        NSString *path_id = [basePath_id stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"id.plist"];

        NSMutableArray *mut_array_id = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path_id] mutableCopy];

        NSMutableDictionary *c0 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSString *idPlistData = [contentDictio objectForKey:@"id"];

        for(c0 in mut_array_id) {
            if([[c0 objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:idPlistData]) {
                [imgRead setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read"]];
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {

    CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(kTableCellSmallMargin*2 + 60, kTableCellSmallMargin, 240, 25);

    UILabel *lblTemp;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                    reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //Initialize Label with tag 1.
    lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label1Frame];
    lblTemp.tag = 1;
    lblTemp.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [lblTemp setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:15.0]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];
    [lblTemp release];

    UIImageView *read=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kTableCellSmallMargin, kTableCellSmallMargin, 60, 60)];
    read.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    read.tag = 6;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:read];
    [read release];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell is cached, so you have to clear it when you want no image, like this:

```
    BOOL found = NO;
    for(c0 in mut_array_id) {
        if([[c0 objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:idPlistData]) {
            [imgRead setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"read"]];
            found = YES;
        }
        else {

        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        [imgRead setImage:nil];
    }
```